# Flask telegram bot unresponsive on server deployment

Tags: flask, bots, telegram

I have been running locally, without `host` param nor `port` param and it has been working well without a webhook (very unintuitive, how is just bot token enough?).
I decided to put my bot on a server. I've created a python3 file and I've now:

- created the webhook on `ipv4` port `8443`

`{"ok":true,"result":true,"description":"Webhook is already set"}`

- edited the lines in `main`:

```
context=('/path_to/cert.pem', '/path_to/privkey.pem')
app.run(host="xxx.xx.xxx.xxx",port="8443", ssl_context=context, debug=False)
```

This gives output of

```
 * Serving Flask app 'xx'
 * Debug mode: off
WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment. Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Running on https://xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:8443
Press CTRL+C to quit
```

Bot is unresponsive.

I've used the following command and it didn't help:

```
sudo ufw allow 8443
```

I've tried running with:

```
context=('/path_to/cert.pem', '/path_to/privkey.pem')
app.run(host="0.0.0.0",port="8443", ssl_context=context, debug=False)
```

And the output is:

```
 * Serving Flask app 'xx'
 * Debug mode: off
WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment. Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Running on all addresses (0.0.0.0)
 * Running on https://xxx.0.0.x:8443
 * Running on https://xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:8443
Press CTRL+C to quit
```

Bot is unresponsive...

Edit: bot code:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import request
from flask import Response
import requests
 
TOKEN = "..."
app = Flask(__name__)
 
def parse_message(message):
    print("message-->",message)
    chat_id = message['message']['chat']['id']
    txt = message['message']['text']
    print("chat_id-->", chat_id)
    print("txt-->", txt)
    return chat_id,txt
 
def tel_send_message(chat_id, text):
    url = f'https://api.telegram.org/bot{TOKEN}/sendMessage'
    payload = {
                'chat_id': chat_id,
                'text': text
                }
   
    r = requests.post(url,json=payload)
    return r
 
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        msg = request.get_json()

        chat_id,txt = parse_message(msg)
        if txt == "hi":
            tel_send_message(chat_id,"Hello!!")
        else:
            tel_send_message(chat_id,'from webhook')

        return Response('ok', status=200)
    else:
        return "<h1>Welcome!</h1>"
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    context=('path/cert.pem', 'path/privkey.pem')
    app.run(host="xxx.xx.xxx.xxx",port="8443", ssl_context=context,debug=False)
```

Comment: I have set up a digitalocean droplet using apache2, used my ipv4:port to set it up.

Comment: what application?

Comment: flask webhook app.

Comment: idk how to check it properly - but I just typed in `curl my_ipv4:8443` and the output is always `curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer`

Comment: If you are using linux then try to check if port is open or not. 
telnet <Hostname> <[PortNumber>

Comment: it works when I try to do it from local  `Trying xxx.xx.xxx.xxx...
Connected to xxx.xx.xxx.xxx.` also curl on just the ip without the port works - gives the website html.

Comment: the second I stop the flask app the connection, of course, no longer can happen so it seems to me everything is good

Comment: It's depend on the bot code.

Comment: Can i see referral documentation from where you are getting help?

Comment: I updated the OP. I am sorry - I don't think it ever worked... another version did that said `hello` instead of `Hello`

Comment: Code seems okay.

Comment: I think the problem is that the IP is my website. Maybe it gets mixed up? Can I separate it somehow? I read that setting separate port would work but I think it doesn't - since `curl` without port gives HTML code for my website. Can I somehow reroute the app not to index but to "xxx.xx.xxx.xxx/tele_app/" for example? I tried a lot of different `@app.route('/'` and no change makes it work

Comment: you need to write route for that like @app.route('/tele_app').

Comment: thanks, I've done that and also set webhook to `xxx.xx.xxx.xxx/tele_app:8443` successfully, chat still unresponsive=(

Comment: you need to deploy it correctly. Follow for help :- https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-gunicorn-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-22-04